# npm command not found in virtual environment pip

Tags: python, node.js, python-3.x, flask

Have searched, but results shown only for brew and not for pip.

I installed node in my my virtual environment

```
pip3.4 install node
```

when I type npm on the prompt, I get the following

```
bash: npm: command not found
```

I even tried installing npm istself, the results is the same.

```
whereis node && whereis npm
```

results the following,

```
node:
npm:
```

Next,

```
which node && which npm
```

returns nothing.

I have no clue as to where is it getting installed. My installation was successful, however.

Any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pip` is a Python package manager. It installs Python packages, from the Python Package Index (pypi).

When you do `pip install node` you install a Python package that happens to be called "node" - this one: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/node. It has nothing to do with NodeJS.

You should use your OS's package manager to install NodeJS and NPM; if you are on a Mac, you should indeed use homebrew.

Comment: Oh My! Managed to get it installed.

Answer (score 2):

You can download and install it from https://nodejs.org/en/

Or you can write

1> For Ubuntu

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_6.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```

2> For fedora

```
curl --silent --location https://rpm.nodesource.com/setup | bash -
yum -y install nodejs
```

3> For IOS

```
brew install node
```

For windows you should download and install by exe file